# libmodbus modbus_read_bits() returns illegal function

Tags: c, register, c++, modbus, tcp-ip

It is all okay when it comes to read registers with:

```
modbus_read_registers(ctx,0,32,destination);
```

It gives me values of 32 different registers. But when it comes to reading bits(coils) in registers i get `illegal function` error.

```
modbus_read_bits(ctx,0,1,dest)
```

After getting this error again and again i made a scanning program like:

```
for(int i=0; i<100000; i++)
   modbus_read_bits(ctx,i,1,dest)
```

All gives me the same error. I have altivar 930(ATV 930).
What to do to read CMD register that has `15 bits` with `logic address 16#2135 = 8501`?

ps: I also tried inputting 0x2135 and 2135. I also get invalid address when i try to read

```
modbus_read_registers(ctx,8501,1,destination);
```

libmodbus.org/docs/v3.0.6/modbus_read_registers.html
http://libmodbus.org/docs/v3.0.6/modbus_read_bits.html

Comment: Some Modbus implementations don't support reading less than 8 coils (one byte) at a time, try requesting 8 coils. Also, what is `dest`? Is it an array or a single byte?

Comment: @RonBeyer hello thank your for your comment it is output, http://libmodbus.org/docs/v3.0.6/modbus_read_registers.html. Let me try 8 coils

Comment: @RonBeyer I still get illegal function with rc= modbus_read_bits(ctx, 0, 8, read_bits); btw uint8_t read_bits[64]; http://libmodbus.org/docs/v3.0.6/modbus_read_bits.html